# What technologies are needed for a self-driving car?

Tags: ai-design, autonomous-vehicles

Google, Tesla or Apple have all built or are building their own self-driving cars. As an expert in a related area, I am interested in knowing at a high level, the systems and techniques that go into self-driving cars.

How easy is it for me to make a tabletop prototype (large enough to accommodate the needed computing power needs)?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need some way to 'see' the area around the car, and to track the speed of nearby objects. Google uses a combination of [LIDAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar), radar, conventional cameras, and occasionally sonar (see  [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-self-driving-cars-work-the-nuts-and-bolts-behind-googles-autonomous-car-program) for a high-level overview). This technology is quite expensive, and can easily cost thousands of US dollars.

However, a bigger obstacle than the expense of the hardware (which would be smaller for a table-top prototype) is the software complexity. Like many major projects, the software for self-driving cars is the result of years of work from AI research teams, and thus extremely difficult to duplicate on your own.

That said, you're not trying to make a state-of-the-art self-driving car.  Assuming you're an expert in image processing and robotics, you can probably create a basic prototype, (like something that drive in a limited table-top environment). However, it's still going to take a lot of time and money.

Comment: The radar is used to detect and track objects under bright ambient lighting, or what is it used for? Thanks!

Comment: Is this radar the same type of radar that is used for detecting the locations of planes and boats?

Comment: This answer really needs some references to improve its reliability.  Right now, you're saying that self-driving cars use AI techniques, but you don't really say 1. for what and 2. which specific techniques. It would be nice to have some examples.